# logrotate -- moving logs by size

Tags: logrotate

I want to move all logs bigger than 1M to "olddir" (`/var/log/old` in this case).

I've googled and read the manpages, but haven't found a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **size** parameter in logrotate.

> Log files are rotated only if they grow bigger then size bytes. If
>   size is followed by k, the size is assumed to be in kilobytes. If the
>   M is used, the size is in megabytes, and if G is used, the size is in
>   gigabytes. So size 100, size 100k, size 100M and size 100 Gare all
>   valid.

It will work. Maybe your configuration is wrong, can you provide it here.

**Edited**

Add `rotate` parameter.

> Log files are rotated count times before being removed or mailed to
>   the address specified in a mail directive. If count is 0, old versions
>   are removed rather than rotated.

You didn't specify your rotate count, so your old log file is removed.

Comment: If I used the size parameter, file contained in the config was deleted.     
Config: `/var/log/foo {
size=1M
olddir /var/log/old` I created foo log file with tr and urandom.

Comment: Yeah, good point, but that's not the point. My aim is to move the logs bigger than value in size parameter do olddir. I don't want to remove or limit the size of file, as I mentioned in first post.

Comment: Just write shell script.